# AWS ip ranges for network restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, network-programming

My team is using AWS on on-premise server at clients HQ.
Client is asking IP adresses to set networking restrictions (outbound).
I found that AWS provides currently used [ip ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-download) for their services.

For example:

- S3 in eu-west-1 region has 8 ip prefixes
- Rabbit MQ (mq.eu-west-1...) - seems doesn't have any specific ip ranges?

We could send ip prefixes from json file but I see few problems:

1. How to avoid ip ranges changes and clients network reconfiguration each time?
2. List of used ip ranges for each service is quite large

I'm having a stupid idea that maybe there is a way to have one ip for each AWS service? For example route all S3 traffic (by using other AWS services) through one endpoint?

Additionally, how to find Amazon MQ ip ranges? In the end we're using something like this: `amqps://{username}:{password}@{url}.mq.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:5671`

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
RabbitMQ broker seems to have static IP